# Google Assistant App Action Integration in android app from Close Beta Test

Tags: android, kotlin, google-assistant-sdk, google-assistant, app-actions

I've been developing an android app with app action integration in it. The action type i've been using are Custom Intent on the shortcut.xml, with an example command like:

```
"Transfer money on my app"
"Show my money on my app"
```

During the development, i'm using Google Assistant App Action Tools Plugin in Android Studio for testing purpose, as the requirements, i logged in with the same Google Account on my Device, android studio, and Google Play Console, and uploaded the app to intertnal testing to be able to test it. I also tried directly using Google Assistant prompt to execute the command (it works well).

After everything was good, I uploaded my app to **Close Testing (Beta)** and added some users to the whitelist so they can access my app with app action in it.

But when the specific users downloaded the closed beta version and tried to trigger the action from Google Assistant, the action are not working. I found out that the app action won't be trigger **when they are using their own Google Email Accounts** instead of my personal email for test.

My question is:

- Is there any documentation that explaining how should i uploaded the
  app in Google Play Console to makes the app actions works by using
  personal email instead of app action tools test email?
- Should we upload the app to full publish/open test to make the app action works on each user?

Thanks A lot.